# Best way to initialize super constructor with fix parameters in Dart?

Tags: dart, constructor, super

I want to initialize super constructor in my dart. the code I want is like this:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
     ChildClass(){
         var startNumber = 4;
         var endNumber  = 8;
         super(startNumber, endNumber);
     }
}
```

but, it will not work in dart code.

Alternative 1:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
     ChildClass() : super(4,8);
}
```

the problem with alternative 1 is that it is not clean code. what is 4 and 8?

Alternative 2:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
     int sNumber = 4;
     int eNumber = 8;

     ChildClass() : super(sNumber, eNumber);
}
```

the problem with alternative 2 is that the field `sNumber` and `eNumber` is redundant because we can use `startNumber` and `endNumber` from `ParentClass` if that field is public

Alternative 3:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
     ChildClass({Int startNumber = 4, int endNumber = 8}) : super(startNumber, endNumber);
}
```

the problem with Alternative 3 is that we can change the value of parameter `startNumber` and `endNumber`

How can I call the super constructor while making clear the meaning of the values being passed?

Comment: Please do not use tags that explicitly say "DO NOT USE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately your problem comes from wanting to make `ParentClass`'s constructor parameters clearer.  Therefore you ideally should make `ParentClass`'s constructor take named parameters:

```dart
class ParentClass {
  int startNumber;
  int endNumber;

  ParentClass({required this.startNumber, required this.endNumber});
}

class ChildClass {
  ChildClass() : super(startNumber: 4, endNumber: 8);
}
```

If you don't have control over `ParentClass`, then another alternative is to use named parameters with a private constructor in `ChildClass` instead:

```dart
class ChildClass {
  ChildClass() : this._internal(startNumber: 4, endNumber: 8);

  ChildClass._internal({required int startNumber, required int endNumber})
    : super(startNumber, endNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use alternative 2 and make the fields private and `const`:

```dart
class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
     static const int _sNumber = 4;
     static const int _eNumber = 8;

     ChildClass() : super(_sNumber, _eNumber);
}
```